# How does := function work in sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm trying to understand in depth some concepts about sbt. At this time I'm trying to understand how the Settings Key Map works. I've seen [this](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/1.0.x/main/src/main/scala/sbt/Keys.scala) and now I want to understand how the `settingAssignMacroImpl` works, based on the signature of the `:=` function.

I see that there's a [macro](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/1.0.x/main-settings/src/main/scala/sbt/std/SettingMacro.scala#L42) but I don't quite understand how the macro expansion works there, so therefore I can't understand how the function assigns the value to the Map. I appreciate any light that you can shed on this.

**EDIT:** As noted by Sarvesh Kumar Singh, my question is about how the macro expands for updating the map, because i see something like this:

```
def settingMacroImpl[T: c.WeakTypeTag](c: blackbox.Context)(t: c.Expr[T]): c.Expr[Initialize[T]] =
    Instance.contImpl[T, Id](c, InitializeInstance, InitializeConvert, MixedBuilder)(Left(t), Instance.idTransform[c.type])
```

But i can't quite understand the expansion process there.

Comment: well... the answerability of this question depends on just "how well do you understand scala macros and reflection ?" So can you add that information with the question ?

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh I understand the basics of macros (AST's, Quasiquotes and expansion). I'll update the question with more details.